# Is wudu area considered tahir (pure) even if it was semi attached to bathroom?

Tags: sharia, fiqh

I heard the local imam of this mosque say you are allowed to say *bismilah* out loud in the wudu area since it is separate from the bathroom. He says, since there is a wall that separates them (even if it is open), then it means bathroom is not connected to wudu area. Is this true ?! Idf so. I'm curious to know how did their reach this ruling in fiqh (i.e: show me the source of your answer)

**Here is a picture of the place:**

[image]

Comment: You are allowed to say bismillah *everywhere*.

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible, and actually encouraged:

> قال موسى عليه السلام: أي رب أقريب أنت فأناجيك، أم بعيد فأناديك؟ قال:
> يا موسى أنا جليس من ذكرني، قال: يا رب فإنا نكون من الحال على حال نعظمك
> أو نجلك أن نذكرك عليها، قال: وما هي؟ قال: الجنابة والغائط. قال: يا
> موسى أذكرني على كل حال.
>
> Moses [image: as] said:
>
> > O God are you near [me] to silently supplicate you, or far to call you.
>
> He said:
>
> > O moses, I'm the companion of the one who remembers me.
>
> Moses said:
>
> > O Allah we might be in a situation that we honor you from being called in it.
>
> Allah said: and what is it?
>
> Moses said:
>
> > impurity and filth.
>
> Allah said:
>
> > O Moses , remember me in every situation.

See also this [source (in Arabic)](http://www.saaid.net/Doat/sudies/61.htm) for other relevant ahadith.